# Android: The Application XXXXX (process com.ough.XXXXX) has stopped unexpectedly . please try again

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to android development, 
I tried to run my first app with eclipse, and the emulator gives me an error :

> The Application XXXXX (process com.ough.XXXXX) has stopped unexpectedly . please try again.

I tried to seek for an answer in the web, but it seems not helping me much.
maybe I set the emulator wrong ?  or my code isnt any good?

my emulator set to :
4.0" WVGA , android 2.2 api level 8  (I tried different stuff and it wont work as well..)

my code is :

```
int counter;
Button add;
Button sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

my androidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ough.thenewboston.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**LOGCAT :**

```
    03-19 13:31:19.014: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
03-19 13:31:24.084: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
03-19 13:31:24.844: E/BatteryService(58): usbOnlinePath not found
03-19 13:31:24.844: E/BatteryService(58): batteryVoltagePath not found
03-19 13:31:24.844: E/BatteryService(58): batteryTemperaturePath not found
03-19 13:31:24.854: E/SurfaceFlinger(58): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
03-19 13:31:28.244: E/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
03-19 13:31:28.244: E/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
03-19 13:31:28.914: E/System(58): Failure starting core service
03-19 13:31:28.914: E/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
03-19 13:31:28.914: E/System(58):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
03-19 13:31:28.914: E/System(58):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
03-19 13:31:28.914: E/System(58):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
03-19 13:31:28.914: E/System(58):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
03-19 13:31:29.334: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-19 13:31:29.334: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
03-19 13:31:29.334: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
03-19 13:31:29.334: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
03-19 13:31:29.334: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
03-19 13:31:30.024: E/ThrottleService(58): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
03-19 13:31:30.464: E/logwrapper(131): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
03-19 13:31:30.504: E/logwrapper(133): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
03-19 13:31:30.574: E/logwrapper(136): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
03-19 13:31:35.136: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(58): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
```

one other thing that is it strange :
it goes "locked" every time when i start the application.  when I open it from the lock mode, it gives me the "sorry.." error line..

any thoughts ?

Comment: You want to look at your logcat. And maybe even post it here.

Comment: please post the full logcat logs...

Comment: Post LOGCAT And AndroidManifest.xml too

Comment: Go to this and watch it again : http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=9

Comment: open eclipse -> window -> show window -> other -> android -> logcat; post what you find there

Comment: Logcat says :  "device disconnected"

Comment: Then connect your device again.

Comment: in the device tab, it says its "online"..

Comment: Why you define : Button add; and Button sub; WHY NOT YOU WRITE IT AS : Button add, sub;

Comment: @ManishAndroid , Dont think thats the problem i have..

Comment: @thormayer : I am using your code and create new app in my eclipse, i also got force close(Null Pointer Exception onClick of sub button), when I changes according what I said in above comment, it runs suuccessfully.

Comment: You have to post your logcat after that someone can help you.

Comment: ok you've found it! :) but that's not the relevant part, your app namespace is never mentioned on those logs, please post the part from "FATAL EXCEPTION" and below..

Comment: @gpasci ok , it says :     newboston (my namespace) , AndriodRuntime    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: come on don't be afraid of posting the WHOLE log. we are NOT psychics and the log is the ONLY thing in the world who knows WHERE and WHAT is crashing your very simple app..please let us help you :)

Comment: hehe , sorry :  here it is :
03-19 13:52:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: I don't think the timestamp has some relevance here, at this point all I can tell you is to read carefully this question and the posted log http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727055/logcat-how-to-trace-a-bug you'll notice that AFTER "FATAL EXCEPTION" there are the relevant log lines...good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer since you haven't shown your logcat and I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code but hopefully it will be helpful and its too much for a comment. If it isn't then I will delete.

If it isn't starting up then, with the code you have, you most likely either have a `null pointer exception` or something not declared correctly in your `manifest`.

Step through and check that these lines aren't `null`

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

Also make sure that you declared the right `menu layout`.

If you don't see any `null` values then the problem is probably in your `manifest`

**Logcat**

I'm pretty sure that when it says "device disconnected" you are in the console tab. You need to be in the logcat tab. You can choose the first line, hold shift, and choose last line then click the "save" icon and save the log then just copy and paste it into your OP.

Comment: I've posted the logcat Im getting.

Comment: Is that your complete `manifest` and logcat? It appears to me that you are trying to access something that you don't have permission to

Comment: Yes, but is there any more to your `manifest` such as `uses-permission`?

Comment: in the "bin" folder I've got "androidManifest.xml" file, I've got a tab named "permissions", but nothing is set there.
on the tab of the xml - I've posted in my question.

Comment: Did you step through to make sure that none of those variables are `null`?

Comment: It depends which ones are `null`. Either you are using the wrong `layout` in `setContentView()` or you aren't using the right `view` names. If one of your `buttons` or your `textview` is null then post your `activity_main` xml